# create new lists from list based on position of element

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list as follows;

```
['US', 20, 'en', 'UK', 21, 'en', 'Fra', 23, 'fr']
```

Which is the most efficient way to create 3 new lists from the above like this?

```
['US', 'UK', 'Fra']
[20, 21, 23]
['en', 'en', 'fr']
```

Comment: I did not downvote but the question was probably downvoted because it is a virtual duplicate -- that is, it would not have required extensive searching to provide an answer instead of asking the question.

Comment: Downvotes are usually the result of lack of research. Have you tried anything yourself and determined that it is too slow for your needs?

Comment: The only way I knew was to run through loops and get the new lists. I guess its a facepalm question. But still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single (interesting) line:

```
>>> l = ['US', 20, 'en', 'UK', 21, 'en', 'Fra', 23, 'fr']
>>> lists = [[l[3*i+j] for i in range(0, int(len(l)/3))] for j in range(0, 3)]
>>> lists
[['US', 'UK', 'Fra'], [20, 21, 23], ['en', 'en', 'fr']]
```

You just have to take `lists[0]`, `lists[1]` and `lists[2]`.

Comment: inner list `[l[i+j] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]` is clearer

Comment: Yes indeed! I was not aware of a third argument for the `range` function.

Answer (score 2):

Slices and a list comprehension should do the trick. It may not strictly be the most efficient possible, but it's concise and readable.

```
data = ['US', 20, 'en', 'UK', 21, 'en', 'Fra', 23, 'fr']
result = [ data[i::3] for i in range(3) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
DATA = ['US', 20, 'en', 'UK', 21, 'en', 'Fra', 23, 'fr']
x= np.array(DATA).reshape(3,len(DATA)/3).T.tolist() 

print x[0]
print x[1]
print x[2]
```

which prints

```
['US', 'UK', 'Fra']
['20', '21', '23']
['en', 'en', 'fr']
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most efficient way, but you can use a slice with a step argument to achieve make it fairly readable:

```
>>> l = ['US', 20, 'en', 'UK', 21, 'en', 'Fra', 23, 'fr']
>>> l[::3]
['US', 'UK', 'Fra']
>>> l[1::3]
[20, 21, 23]
>>> l[2::3]
['en', 'en', 'fr']
```

Comment: Or to actually create the requested list, `[l[::3],l[1::3],l[2::3]]`

Comment: @aestrivex The question only mentions creating three lists, not a list of lists.